# Cuenta Intentos()

Tags: python-3.x

tengo un problema con un ejercicio de la universidad

No encuentro una función adecuada para iniciar el contador de veces que entra en el while

> Recibe por parámetro un número contraseña (entre 1 y 999). Pide al
> usuario que ingrese un número hasta que adivine la contraseña; si el
> número ingresado es mayor que la contraseña, debe mostrar el texto "Mi
> número es menor, intente nuevamente"; si el número ingresado es menor,
> debe mostrar el texto "Mi número es mayor, intente
> nuevamente".Devuelve como resultado la cantidad de intentos realizados

y tengo:

```
def cuenta_intentos(passw):
    
    passw = passw
    contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))

    while contra < passw:
        print('Mi número es mayor, intente nuevamente')
        contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))
        
    while contra > passw:    
        print('Mi número es menor, intente nuevamente')
        contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))
        break
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿Cuál sería tu problema?, mencionas un problema y solo veo un encabezado de el problema que debes resolver.

Comment: No encuentro una función adecuada para iniciar el contador de veces que entra en el while.

Comment: Ahh deberías empezar por mencionar eso en tu publicación no crees ??

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema simplemente es una mala implementacion de logica.

si haces esto:

```
while contra < passw:
    print('Mi número es mayor, intente nuevamente')
    contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))
```

Y luego ingreso un numero mayor, saldre de ahi.. pero que va a pasar cuando a la siguiente:

```
while contra > passw:    
    print('Mi número es menor, intente nuevamente')
    contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))
```

Ingrese un numero menor? simplemente tu progrma no va a hacer lo que esperas que haga, no va a volver para atras.

En realidad, vos necesitas controlar si es diferente lo que ingreso al pass, luego de ello, controlar si es mayor o menor.. y en base a eso contar los intentos...

Fijate que se necesita un solo while...

```
passw = passw
contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))

while contra != passw:
    if contra < passw:
        print('Mi número es mayor, intente nuevamente')
    elif contra > passw
        print('Mi número es menor, intente nuevamente')
    cont = cont + 1
    contra = int(input('Ingrese la contraseña: '))
print('Lo encontraste!')
```

Comment: @tomas no estas en tu casa.. por favor, mantene el vocabulario de una forma decente. Gracias. y por favor recorda hacer el [tour] y leer [ask]